# Azure ML Execute Python Module: Network I/O Disabled?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there no way to connect to a URL from azure ml and get it's content

**my code:**

```
import requests
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):    
    b= requests.get("http://www.google.com",timeout=30)
    dataframe1 = b.content
    return dataframe1
```

Is there any change need to be made to connect to URL

**ERROR:**

```
Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for more information:
 ---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------
data:text/plain,Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 167, in batch
odfs = mod.azureml_main(*idfs)
File "C:\temp\azuremod.py", line 24, in azureml_main
b= requests.get("http://www.google.com",timeout=30)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
return request('get', url, **kwargs)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 559, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 375, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)

---------- End of error message from Python  interpreter  ---------
```

Or is there any change needed to be made on the azure ml settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*UPDATE* 1/28/2016

Network I/O for `Execute Python Script` is now supported.

*Out of date*

Network I/O is not support from Execute Python Modules. In order to execute such a program, you should instead launch a virtual machine(Windows or Linux your choice).

Windows:

1. RDP into Virtual Machine
2. Install your choice of Python
3. You can drag and drop your Python program from your Local Windows machine onto your RDP screen to transfer your code
4. Then run your program

Ubuntu:

1. SSH into your virtual machine using Cygwin or Putty(Windows) or Terminal SSH (mac) `ssh yourUserName@yourAzureVM.cloudapps.net`
2. install Python `sudo apt-get install python`
3. open your preferred Linux text editor `vi myProgram.py`
4. Copy and Paste your code into the editor (leave vi with esc `:wq` )
5. Run your code `python myProgram.py`

To move data from your VM to AzureML please check out the [Azure-MachineLearning-ClientLibrary-Python](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-MachineLearning-ClientLibrary-Python) on Github

Comment: This can not be done within only AzureML. Due to the potential for abuse(DDOS attack, etc), Network I/O is limited to the main Azure subscription. If you are not the workspace administrator, you will have to reach out to them to set you up a Virtual Machine. If you are an AzureML Free user you will have to run your program locally.

Comment: Thanks mate so with only azure ml it is not possible .So i have to connect my azure vm output to azure ml then process them.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer with a link to our Python Library for moving data into your workspace, this should help make the process even easier

Comment: Dan Ciborowski - where can I find any documentation on networking in Execute Python Script module?