# Python machine learning API - Microsoft Azure / AWS Lambda

Tags: python, azure, amazon-web-services, lambda

I created a Machine Learning classifier with Python, using word2vec and I want to create an API to use it in production.
What's the easiest way to do that please ?

I heard of AWS Lambda and Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio but I am not sure it would work with word2vec.
For example with AWS Lambda, would I need to reload the libraries each time (it takes a while to do that). 
And can I install any Python package with Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio and choose any kind of machine (need a lot of RAM for word2vec) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now, according to the offical document `Execute Python machine learning scripts in Azure Machine Learning Studio` about [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-execute-python-scripts#limitations) for customizing Python installation (No.4 item), as below.

> ***Inability to customize Python installation***. Currently, the only way to add custom Python modules is via [the zip file mechanism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn955437.aspx#Anchor_3) described earlier. While this is feasible for small modules, it is cumbersome for large modules (especially those with native DLLs) or a large number of modules.

Unfortunately, the python package like `word2vec` which includes some C modules could not be installed customize on Azure ML studio.

The only workaround way is to create a VM to install `word2vec` for Python and create a webservice in Python for calling in the `Execute Python Script` module of Azure ML studio via network IO, that as the answer of [Azure ML Execute Python Module: Network I/O Disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297579/azure-ml-execute-python-module-network-i-o-disabled) said Azure ML studio support Network IO for `Execute Python Script` module now.